# Change owner / user access

Tags: permissions, vmware, shared-folders

I am new to the Ubuntu/Linux world and I'm loving it! Recently, I learned how to create my first virtual machine in VMware, but I had a really hard time getting the VM tools to work through the terminal command. After completing the setup, I found out that I am unable to perform bidirectional actions through the shared folders because I do not have user access. The shared folders do not acknowledge me as the administrator. I was wondering if anyone could offer any scripts to use in the terminal to help me correct this issue.

[image]